How to disable search engine choice screen?
Using karma for unit-testing in an Angular project works fine. With a new Chrome version a "search engine selection" windows pops up on each npm run test.
How to disable this ?

Can you add some details as the config file that declare the command?

There is a command-line-argument  disable-search-engine-choice-screen that disables that popup.
using that argument is a little bit tricky (use the right number of dashes)
in the file karma.config.js  replace
   browsers: ['Chrome'],

with:
    browsers: ["MyChromeWithoutSearchSelect"],
    customLaunchers: {
      MyChromeWithoutSearchSelect: {
        base: "Chrome",
        flags: ["-disable-search-engine-choice-screen"],
      },
    },


I'll add some information relevant to Angular 18 to @Reinhard's response.
If your project doesn't yet have a karma.config.js file, you can create it by running the command:
ng generate config karma
This command will create a file with default settings and will also add a reference to it in angular.json.
Next, in karma.config.js, follow Reinhard's advice and replace
browsers: ['Chrome'],

